# UdpClient Send Receive

Tags: c#, .net, udpclient

First I want to say that I read: [UdpClient, Receive() right after Send() does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221783/udpclient-receive-right-after-send-does-not-work)

My question is: is this the normal standard way to handle UDP communications. Set up one UdpClient for send and another for receive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/222503/356178) is the standard way to do UDP sockets in .NET

Answer (score 1):

you can actually do this on a Server using Sockets as well checkout this link to see if this will help you in anyway.[how to configure the server socket](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/malarch/archive/2005/11/18/494769.aspx)